# angularjs firebase app: can't display data

Tags: javascript, html, firebase, firebase-realtime-database

i am just starting with firebase and angular 
i want to display some data from firebase in my browser
here is my code

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<head>

    <!-- Firebase -->

    <script src="//cdn.firebase.com/js/client/2.2.1/firebase.js"></script>
</head>
<body>


    title :<title></title><br>
    content :<content></content><br>
    <script type="text/javascript" >
    var t=document.querySelector('title');
    var c=document.querySelector('content');

    var ref= new Firebase('https://fir-app-4394a.firebaseio.com');
    ref.on('child_changed',function(snapshot){
        var data=snapshot.val();
        console.log("title: " + data.title);
        console.log("content: " + data.content);
        t.innerHTML=data.title;
        c.innerHTML=data.content;
    });

    </script>
</body></html>
```

this is the data in my firebase which i want to display
content: " fffff"
 title: "rfff "

I dont know why there is no connection with the firebase 
thanks for your help :D

Comment: Format your code. And how is it about Angular?

Comment: i followed this https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=qxAojyj8LdI

Answer (score 0):

You are using firebase legacy SDK. Set it to the new one.

```
<script src="https://www.gstatic.com/firebasejs/3.1.0/firebase.js"></script>
```

And then you will need to start your app a little diferrent. Instead of going with `new Firebase` you must use `firebase.initializeApp(config);` and `firebase.database().ref()` to get the ref.

```
<script>
  // Initialize Firebase
  var config = {
    apiKey: "",
    authDomain: "",
    databaseURL: "",
    storageBucket: "",
  };
  firebase.initializeApp(config);
  var ref= firebase.database().ref();
</script>
```

To get your `config` details go to the new console overview by clicking in your app name and then hit **Add Firebase to your Web app**.

Comment: yes i know about it already but what i cant understand why I cant see the connection to the firebase nothing is shown

Comment: @TesnimJemli You wont see because you are not connected. You need to use `firebase.initializeApp`

Comment: I did use it after config as u mentioned before

Comment: @TesnimJemli Ok, nice, so update the question with your current code and your current status.

Answer (score 0):

Try using Angularfire. Current version for firebase is 3.2.0 and angularfire is 2.x.x .

Check out the docs [here](https://github.com/firebase/angularfire/blob/master/docs/guide/introduction-to-angularfire.md).

Answer (score 0):

I followed this link to configure my firebase 
https://github.com/angular/angularfire2/blob/master/docs/1-install-and-setup.md
its with a different generator but its ok i get the result i was looking for and that's sufficient 
thank you